# Beanstalk app CPU spikes

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are running a docker container on AWS elastic beanstalk, which was running fine for a few weeks but suddenly started to experience very sudden CPU spikes (from ~5% to ~60% in a matter of minutes), who sometimes drop back down quickly, and sometimes stay high for enough time to produce an autoscaling event and spin up a few instances for extra help (Which are terminated some time after that when the CPU spike dies down).

The funny thing is, I wanted to investigate the problem today, so I've sshed into every instance (4 in total) and ran `top` on all of them, trying to locate the CPU consuming process, and was surprised to discover all instances have ~15% CPU busy (system + user combined), while the EBS monitoring page still shows the servers are at 60% CPU.
I've measured these figures for the good part of the hour, making sure the CPU high load stays high, while the `top` command still shows low values.

I've also tried to measure CPU for a while using the advice found here -https://askubuntu.com/questions/22021/how-to-log-cpu-load, and got the same very low CPU stats when querying the server directly.

My question is - is it possible AWS monitoring system is not showing me accurate data? Is there anyway to verify the data displayed in the monitoring page?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So the AWS monitoring system is showing 60 Percent utilization for each instance is that correct? And "top" is showing 15% for each instance?

Comment: Actually, AWS beanstalk does not show each instance CPU separately, but rather the average of all of them. Your question made me get to the bottom of this since I went and looked at all EC2 servers individually, and find that while the calculated amount showed in the top command is ~15%, there was a process consuming ~60% of the CPU power (I'm guessing those 60% amount to 15% of the entire instance processing power)
Thanks.

Comment: So you are all set now right?

Comment: I do believe so, I guess I was just misreading the stats.